# Does LuaJ support __gc metamethod functionality

Tags: java, lua, luaj

When experimenting with LuaJ on some personal (trivial) projects, I found that I seemed unable to make use of `__gc` in table metatables as shown in the example below:

```
do
    local tbl = {id="tblID"}
    setmetatable(tbl,{__gc=function(self) print("gc'd :"..self.id) end })
    print(tbl.id)
end
collectgarbage('collect')
```

Though I'm aware in LuaJ `collectgarbage()` is a redundant function call, due to LuaJ relying on Java's own garbage collection instead, I included it as some other interpreters seem to require it ( e.g. Lua's own at http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

The given example seems to function in the online interpreter provided above.

I'm currently assuming the fault is either with LuaJ in some fashion or garbage collection occurring at the end of program execution not calling __gc metamethods on collected objects.

I've tried giving java enough time to GC the table before the application ends by providing a lengthy wait period following the call along with a call to `System.gc()`
to suggest garbage collection to the runtime, all currently to no avail.